# API endpoints is working in localhost but not working with the URL

Tags: node.js, rest, express

the API endpoints are working in localhost but at the moment I'm deploying it to the server, and some of the endpoints are not working.

```
http://localhost:xxxx/api/endpoint ==> working

https://myapiurl.com/api/endpoint ==> not working
```

Here is my Nginx configuration :

```
root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name golivegameplan.com www.golivegameplan.com https://golivegameplan.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }



    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/golivegameplan.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/golivegameplan.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if you're getting a CORS error.
Is it functioning in postman?

Comment: No, it functioning in postman in postman, I have updated the SSL. It's not the CORS error I guess, as 70% of the API is working, newly deployed once are not working

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `0.0.0.0` in the `proxy_pass` directive instead of `localhost`?

Comment: No, I did not. I'll try once!

Comment: Did this help? Could you figure it out?